# How to transfer and auto redirect url to subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have domain is domain.com
And 2 link url:

```
domain.com?user=abc
domain.com?user=def
```

=> How to config and redirect new url (follow format above) for below result

```
abc.domain.com
def.domain.com
```

How to ideas?

Comment: Why not do it through code?

Comment: Do subdomains `abc.domain.com` and `def.domain.com` actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

In PHP you can use something like
`header('Location: ....');` 
[See PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

In Apache config you would use `RewriteRule` from module mod_rewrite
[See Apache Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

In Nginx config you would use `rewrite` from module ngx_http_rewrite_module
[See Nginx config](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)